# How can the pre-measurement be fulfilled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

In the decoherence program, the pre-measurement refers to the evolution in which the system and apparatus form a Schmidt state.
In Maximilian Schlosshauer's review article(2005), I read "the linearity of the Schrödinger equation entails that the total system SA evolves from an initial product state to a state of Schmidt form."

Why? Is it an assumption? How can this process be fulfilled?

Comment: The paper is here: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0312059 - relevant section, page 4 top

Comment: As long as there is interaction between the system and the apparatus, the initial product state will generically evolve into a non-product form, which can be further brought into the Schmidt form.

Comment: I agree that for any state we can find a corresponding basis such that it become schmidt. but such a basis is not the same for all states. Then, in a specific measurement, we chose the relevant eigenstates(|Sn>,|An>) as basis, how can we ensure that the product state evolves into the Schmidt form in this basis?